# Add associated products to quote but not cart

Tags: magento, cart

I have created a new product type in Magento. However, I am having difficulty adding all of its associated products to the `sales_flat_quote_item` table. I only want the associated products added to the table and only the main parent product visible in the cart.

I am real close to achieving this. Right now only the parent item is visible in the cart when adding it to the cart. However, only one of it's associated products are being listed in the above mentioned table.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Product_Type_Custom extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract {
........

    protected function _prepareProduct(Varien_Object $buyRequest, $product, $processMode)
{
    $qty = $buyRequest['qty'];
    $associatedQty = $buyRequest['associated_qty'];

    if($qty >= 1) {
        $result = parent::_prepareProduct($buyRequest, $product, $processMode);
        if (is_array($result)) {
            $product = $this->getProduct($product);

            foreach($buyRequest['associated'] as $associated){
                if($associated){
                    $subProducts[] = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($associated);
                }
            }

            foreach($subProducts as $subProduct){
                if($subProduct){
                    $product->setCartQty($qty);
                    $product->addCustomOption('product_qty_'.$subProduct->getId(), $associatedQty[$subProduct->getId()], $subProduct);

                    $product->addCustomOption('associated_product_' . $subProduct->getId(), $associatedQty[$subProduct->getId()]);

                }
            }

                    $_result = $subProduct->getTypeInstance(true)->_prepareProduct(
                        $buyRequest,
                        $subProduct,
                        $processMode
                    );

            if (!isset($_result[0])) {
                return Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Cannot add the item to shopping cart');
            }

            $_result[0]->setParentProductId($product->getId())
                ->addCustomOption('parent_product_id', $product->getId());

            $result[] = $_result[0];
            return $result;

        } else {
            return $this->getSpecifyOptionMessage();
        }
    } else {
        return $this->getQtyMessage();
    }
}

........
}
```

Right now only the associated product '53' is being added as a child product. I am still missing the other two. Basically, the `foreach($subProducts as $subProduct)` loop will loop 3 three times with the three associated products. I am assuming somewhere along the lines in Magento it is only using the last looped product.

Any advice or help with this would be great. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out. I just had to shift the following into the foreach loop instead of outside of it.

```
$_result[0]->setParentProductId($product->getId())
           ->addCustomOption('parent_product_id', $product->getId());

$result[] = $_result[0];
```